# New Computer, Windows XP Installation Not Seeing SSD HD (error 0x0000007b 0xf78d2524 0xc000034)

Tags: windows-xp, ssd

**TLDR:**  Got a new computer and after failing at installing XP have come to the conclusion that system is not seeing my solid state hard drive [link to model below]

---

So I unpack the new computer and pop in the Windows XP disc, starts running through the blue screen install then stops and shows an error:

```
0x0000007b 0xf78d2524 0xc000034
```

Lovely.

So I try rebooting and starting again and soon I see the same error.  I try a different Windows XP disc [I've used both successfully in the past on other computers] -- same issue.

So I do some reading online and apparently 0x0000007b errors have to do with the boot disc [in this case it is [Kingston SSDNow V Series Gen II 128GB 2.5IN SATA2 Solid State Disk Flash Drive](http://ncix.com/products/?sku=50543&vpn=SNV425-S2/128GB&manufacture=Kingston)] -- one of the suggestions is that sometimes depending on which SATA port you put your CD/DVD drive into, the system can get confused and think the CD/DVD drive is the boot disc.  So I put the HDD into the SATA0 port and put the DVD drive into SATA1.  Reboot and same error.  So I try putting the DVD drive all the way into the SATA4 port and reboot.  This time we get a bit deeper in the Windows XP install, right to where you need to select which partition you would like to install to.  I would expect to see a single 128gb of unpartitioned space but instead I see "no drive found."  So now after seeing this and snooping around in the BIOS I am thinking that my system is just not seeing the HDD at all.

Is there any way to make my computer see my HDD so I can install XP on it?  Keep in mind it is a new computer with nothing on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to install the SATA/RAID drive necessary, in order for XP to read the drive. You can normally find that on your computer manufacturer's site.

Comment: Can I install that BEFORE the windows install though?

Comment: There should be an option when to install before you actually install and partition your drive. If you read on the scrolling text as the drivers are loading from the XP disc, it'll ask you if you need to install a SATA/RAID driver and to press F6 if you need to to install it. That's where you install the driver. You'd need the driver on a USB flash drive or do it old school with a floppy drive.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, first of all the DVD drive is on SATA and it seems to be totally fine and I snooped around in the BIOS and these seems to be references to both SATA and RAID.  Also I'm kind of a hardware n00b but there's no RAID as it is just one drive?  Maybe that's irrelevant but I feel like this isn't quite it.

Comment: I'd give it a shot. I've had the exact same issue, where installing XP would BSOD on me because it couldn't find the driver. This happened on my HP mini 311 when reinstalling with a fresh XP install instead of the restore DVD that I ordered.

Comment: I know you accepted, but I'm just curious. Did that work? Or did you do something else to fix the install?

Comment: No it worked, actually was kind of inconsistent which was weird.  I got a couple different errors a few times.  Eventually it worked though.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [F6 option](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314859) at the very start of setup to load the sata driver, this is a pain though, it requires the use of a floppy drive connected to the motherboard, not an option these days for most motherboards, you can try a usb floppy drive but there are only [certain models XP setup will recognize.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916196/en-us)

.

The easier solution is to use DriverPacks  to slipstream "Mass storage" drivers into the XP CD, no need to use F6 now!

Driver packs tutorial, read carefully.

http://forum.driverpacks.net/viewtopic.php?id=1449

Download software "Driverpacks Base"

http://driverpacks.net/downloads

You can install other driver packs besides the "Mass Storage", but this will bloat the size of the XP install to DVD size, The only driver packs I suggest to slipstream are

Mass Storage, Chipset, Lan, CPU

This will keep it a size to fit on a CD. If you want All the drivers slipstreamed it will require a DVD burner to make the DVD and a DVD drive on the installation target PC.

I don't change any of the default settings when using the software, just pick the driver packs you want to slipstream and create the ISO image.

If you use other customizing software for other reasons than drivers such as Nlite, use Nlite first then driver packs last or install problems will result. Only use DP to slip drivers, do not use Nlite for this task.

Start with clean unmodified Installation files when using DP for best results

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, you may also try to hop into the BIOS and flip the AHCI switch to IDE.

This worked for me when the XP setup program wouldn't recognize my Corsair 60GB SSD.

Comment: This just worked for me too!  Wow.  Thanks!  I had just assumed that an SSD would look exactly the same to the OS as any other hard drive.  Apparently not.  On my old thinkpad Z61m I had to change AHCI to "Compatability Mode" in the BIOS.